# Kafka JDBC sink connector - is it possible to store the topic data as a json in DB

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka JDBC sink connector - is it possible to store the topic data as a json into the postgre DB. Currently it parse each json data from Topic and map it to the corresponding column in the table.

If anyone has worked on a similar case, can you please help me what are the config details I should add inside the connector code.

I used the below code. But, it didn't work.

```
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
```

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC sink requires a Struct type (JSON with Schema, Avro, etc)

If you want to store a string, that string needs to be the value of a key that corresponds to a database column. That string can be anything, including delimited JSON

Comment: i want to store the Topic data as it is in Table. For example,  {"id": 999, "product": "foo", "quantity": 100, "price": 50} this topic data should be stored in table as a json , instead it creates a separate column for each json data.

Comment: Yes. It's behaving exactly as documented. Like I said, you'll have to "wrap" your object into a string value, and key it by the database column name where you want to put the string. I.e `{"myCol": "{\"id\": 999, \"product\": \"foo\", \"quantity\": 100, \"price\": 50}"}`... However if you actually want to "store JSON", I suggest not using a relational database and instead use a document database like Mongo or Couchbase